# How to install Cynogenmod on a Galaxy S w/ Android 2.1

Tags: cyanogenmod, samsung-galaxy-s, rom-flashing

I got a Galaxy S today. It shows a *"Firmware version 2.1-update1"*, which I suppose is Android 2.1.1. I want to install an up-to-date Android version on it, so I thought I'd turn to Cyanogenmod. I have never done this. (In fact, I am still at the state where I am a bit hazy about what terms as "rooting", "flashing" etc. exactly apply to.)

I have found [this step-by-step guide to install Cyanogenmod on a Galaxy S](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Install_CM_for_galaxysmtd) and tried to follow it, but I failed miserably. I got as far as #5, where I would put the ClockworkMod recovery file onto the phone, but there
`heimdall flash --kernel zImage --no-reboot`
gives me a
`Initialising connection...

Detecting device...

Claiming interface...

ERROR: Claiming interface failed!`

I have put several hours into this, but now I am stumped for good. I used to get `failed to detect compatible device` when I started this. After lots of searching the web, installed Samsung's Kies software, because it is supposed to allow the phone to be updated to Android 2.2, which some guides seem to presume as a starting point. However, I was unable to get Kies to even recognize the device. But its installation seems to have gotten me past Heimdall's error. At other places, however, I have found statements saying that one should *uninstall* Kies in order to get Heimdall working...

So what did I do wrong? How am I to proceed? What should I try next?

Answer (score 1):

If you are **NOT** rooted, you can root your phone with [this](http://depositfiles.com/files/n0dcxce3t)

When you are rooted, try this -

1. Install [ROM Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.koushikdutta.rommanager&hl=en)

   1. Flash ClockworkMod Recovery (Via ROM Manager)
   2. Download Cyanogenmod (Via ROM Manager)
   3. Install ROM (Via ROM Manager)

That's it, very simple and easy.

Comment: Try what if rooted?

Comment: This phone is not rooted. Would it be easier if it was? That ROM manager seems to be incompatible with this OS version.

Comment: Dont u need to be premium to download it from rom manager

Answer (score 1):

Your phone need to be rooted, otherwise you can't install ROM Manager because it needs root acces.

If you rooted your phone just download cyanogenmod and install it trought CWM (ClockWorkMod Recovery)

Download CM: http://get.cm and search your device or go to http://cyanogenmod.com an click on get cyanogenmod and click on your device.

I think you should download an Stable mod because your are an custom rom noob as i see.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Currently I lack the time to play with this, but I'll try ASAP.

Comment: The guide says: Rooting the stock firmware is neither recommended nor necessary.